# Iterating over prefixes of multiple arrays/lists in Haskell efficiently

Tags: arrays, list, haskell, sum, iteration

Given three sorted arrays, I need to pick exactly `m` elements from them in total with the minimum sum. An additional constraint is that at least `r` of them must come from the first two. Here is my attempt:

```
solve :: [Int]->[Int]->[Int]->Int->Int->Int
solve xs ys zs m r = mini [ (xs'!!i) + (ys'!!j) + (zs'!!k) |
  i <- [max' (len ys - m) .. len xs],
  j <- [max' (r-i) .. len ys],
  k <- [max' (m-i-j) .. len zs],
  i+j+k == m,  
  i+j>=r
  ] where
      mini ws = if null ws then (-1) else minimum ws
      [xs',ys',zs'] = map (scanl (+) 0) [xs, ys, zs]
      max' x = max x 0
      len ws = min (length ws) m
```

(Since the arrays are sorted, I'm considering their prefixes of length `i,j,k` that satisfy the constraints, and summing them up using `scanl`.)

My worry is whether this is too inefficient, because of `!!`. Also, I am wondering if `scanl` is helping at all. Is this concern valid, and if so how can we fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fundamental operation is that of merging sorted lists.

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge xs@(x:xs') ys@(y:ys')
  | x <= y = x : merge xs' ys
  | otherwise = y : merge xs ys'
```

We can merge the first two, and combine the result with the third.

```
solve :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> Int -> Int -> a
solve xs ys zs m r = sum . take m  $ prefix ++ rest
  where
    (prefix, suffix) = splitAt r (merge xs ys)
    rest = merge suffix zs
```

Comment: "any sufficiently complex index manipulation code is half-baked bug-ridden implementation of mergesort." surely someone must've said this! :)

Comment: @WillNess, I think this exercise is an interesting example of how an instructor teaching or writing about hammers will be in the right frame of mind to present problems about nails, while a carpenter who learned to hammer years ago may not notice, out of context, that a problem is about nails.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid `!!` while keeping the algorithm the same using `zip`:

```
solve xs ys zs m r = mini [ x + y + z |
    (i, x) <- zip [max' (len ys - m) .. len xs] xs',
    -- ...
```

I guess a naive compiler might recompute the second and third `zip`s each time through the loops. You could defend against this source of inefficiency by binding them to names in the `where` block.

```
-- ...
    (i, x) <- indexedXs
-- ...
where
    indexedXs = zip [max' (len ys - m) .. len xs] xs'
    -- ...
```

(You may need to `drop` some elements from `indexedYs` and `indexedZs` in the later parts of the comprehension.)

Probably the best performance boost will come from making the conditions at the end of your list comprehension true by construction. The second one (`i+j >= r`) is already so, because you are choosing `j` to be at least `r-i`. So you can just delete that line to improve performance without changing what result you get. You can cause the first one, `i+j+k==m`, to be true by setting `k=m-i-j` (i.e. doing no iteration at all at this level). So, the end of the comprehension will look like this, instead:

```
    -- ...
    z <- take 1 (drop (m-i-j) zs')
    -- N.B. no conditions here
    ] where
    -- ...
```

Finally, I suspect you will get a bit of a win by computing the lengths of `xs`, `ys`, and `zs` just once instead of every time through the loops. So:

```
    -- use lenXs instead of len xs, etc. in the comprehension...
    ] where
    lenXs = length (take m xs)
    lenYs = length (take m ys)
    -- ...
```

I have also embedded a subtle change above: `length (take m xs)` will be slightly faster than `min m (length xs)` when the length of `xs` is much bigger than `m` (because it will look at much less of the list). This also gracefully deals with infinite lists, unlike your version.

Also, beware: I have thought about but not actually run the code suggestions above. Test the !$*# out of them!

Comment: I'm not so convinced indices are useful.

Comment: @dfeuer It is probably possible to do this without indices. But it will certainly be significantly uglier, and more difficult for a reader to understand the algorithm. Sometimes that is a good tradeoff, but for what is obviously intended to be an introductory exercise I think it is the wrong one.

Comment: Not the least bit uglier!

Comment: Please see my answer.